# Emacs autocomplete-mode extension for ESS and R

Tags: r, emacs, autocomplete, ess

Is there an R-extension to Emacs [autocomplete-mode](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html) that can be used with [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/)?

If the extension doesn't exist I'd also appreciate any hints for writing one!

Comment: VitoshKa, can you please post your source?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an ac-source for R [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoCompleteSources#toc2). I recall struggling with it and finally wrote my own which at that time was much faster, but buggy since I didn't manage to make prefix regexp work properly.

EDIT: the newest ESS (only svn currently) has out-of-the-box integration with auto-complete. I have added the instructions to the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESSAuto-complete).

[image]

Comment: OK, I tried it and seems to be quite good, I think it should be enough for me.

Comment: I can only get it to have the drop-down list, not any of the other functionality? help?

Comment: @Dualinity It is explained in the wiki. Help doesn't pop up automatically as far as I remember. There are tons of options for auto-complete. You can make it pop-up. I simply bind it to M-h and whenever in ac-mode-map.

Comment: That ac-completing-map is not existing for me (AC 1.3.1).

Comment: @Dualinity Hm, ac 1.3.1 is utterly old. Install one from https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete  (clone and add require, stuff as usual)

Comment: error gives: "popup-create: Keyword argument :mouse-face not one of (:min-height :around :face :selection-face :scroll-bar :margin-left :margin-right :symbol :parent :parent-offset)"

Comment: @VitoshKa thanks for the tip.  I have:
(setq ess-use-auto-complete t)
(defun my-ac-emacs-ess-mode ()
  (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-R ac-source-filename))
  )
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'my-ac-emacs-ess-mode)
(add-hook 'inferior-ess-mode-hook 'my-ac-emacs-ess-mode)
in my init file and it seems like autocomplete works in my inferior ess buffer, but not my R script.  Can you provide documentation to correctly set this up?  Thanks!

Comment: @VinhNguyen `ac-source-R` will work in script buffer only if the buffer is associated with the subprocess (C-c C-z, or C-c C-s,or just evaluate something). In addition, you don't need any of your configuration with the recent version of ESS. Autocomplete is detected and configured automatically,

Comment: I find for the latest version of ess, autcomplete is nto detected an configured automatically.

Answer (score 4):

[auto-complete-acr](https://github.com/myuhe/auto-complete-acr.el/blob/master/auto-complete-acr.el) is auto-complete sources.

it is more useful than ac-R.

add to .emacs below.

```
(require ‘auto-complete)
(require ‘auto-complete-acr)
```