# Is it possible to get code completion for R in Emacs ESS similar to what is available in Rstudio?

Tags: r, emacs, autocomplete, ess, rstudio

Rstudio has a great code completion feature. It provides a quick view of functions that start with a given string, as well as function and parameter definitions.

ESS is powerful enough, familiar to me, and integrated into Emacs, where I conduct most of my work -  so I am hesitant to move, but this feature is making me consider such a move.

Is it possible to integrate this feature into Emacs ESS?

Is there anything similar to this for Emacs ESS?

Any hope that there will be (and if so, how could I support such an effort?)

[image]

Comment: Oh, all right. I _will_ try YetAnotherIDE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs autocomplete-mode extension for ESS and R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682459/emacs-autocomplete-mode-extension-for-ess-and-r)

Comment: it's similar, but surely not a dupe!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You do get the completion thanks to the rcompgen package by Deepayan (now "promoted" into base R as part of the utils package). So when I type

```
lm(
```

and hit TAB a new buffer opens which gets me the left-hand side of your window above: the available options to the function at hand.  I don't think you can show the help directly though.

There is / was also a way to get context-sensitive help in the mini-buffer when typing but I have forgottten how/where that gets turned on.

Comment: Emacs is to Eddelbuettel as honey is to Winnie the Pooh. ;)

Comment: Quite right. Also makes my bed, serves me coffee and feeds the cat.

Comment: ...and responds to stackoverflow questions and comments.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich:  Ah, that's the secret.

Comment: @Dirk Re: Last para -- Maybe `ess-eldoc`?

Comment: I'm afraid that you cannot get pop-up help for function formal arguments, but you can type `C-c C-v` to get help in another buffer.

Comment: Dirk, @Joshua: I will log those as feature requests for RStudio 0.95. ;)

Comment: Are you sure about this Dirk? **codetools** is only a "recommended" package in R. This auto-complete functionality was from Deepyan's **rcompgen** package which was "recommended" but is now in base R as apart of the **utils** package.

Answer (score 20):

[EDIT: This is an old answer and auto-complete package dropped out of fashion since then. Please use [`company-mode`](http://company-mode.github.io/) instead. It should work by default. Wiki configuration entry is [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESS-company).]

Recent versions of ESS (> v.12.02) integrate with [auto-complete](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) package out of the box (you need not configure anything, just install auto-complete). It provides help on arguments as well as function help. I added detailed instructions to the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESSAuto-complete)

[image: Ess-ac screenshot]

[image]

Ess-eldoc was also rewritten and from v.12.02 it's active by default, so you don't need to configure anything.

Comment: Vitoshka is that `solarize` theme that you're using?

Comment: yes @aL3xa, after years of using calm forest dark theme I've switched to `solarize` recently and am quite happy with it :)

Comment: FWIW, I'm using tango dark theme and I'm happy with it, but I'd like to try out solarize. Looks nice.

Comment: How did you setup your .emacs so that help is shown in full "glory"? :) On my machine the corresponding help pop-up is rather small and ugly.

Comment: @fotNelton  Sorry for being late. Didn't notice the response. I have `ac-quick-help-prefer-pos-tip` set to `t` and `(require 'pos-tip)`. You can play with colors as on examples in the wiki link above.

Comment: @VitoshKa Oh, no problem at all, thank you very much for your answer. I'll give it a try as soon as possible :)

Comment: @VitoshKa I followed your [wiki edits](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ESSAuto-complete), putting in `(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "M-d") 'ac-quick-help)` but the "M-h" is still bound to "mark paragraph". I tried other keybindings and it doesn't work either. Could you check this please?

Comment: @Heisenberg, you are binding it to `M-d` not `M-h`. Consider using compay-mode btw. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Or maybe we should all use search:

[Emacs autocomplete-mode extension for ESS and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682459/emacs-autocomplete-mode-extension-for-ess-and-r)

I don't want to be grumpy, I found this few hours ago and I'm still shocked. It works like a charm. Though I still prefer the old-style pop-ups. =)

Comment: that's not really an answer, its more of a comment, but the point could be better made with a vote to close as exact duplicate, as I have done.