# Customizing the ESS environment for R

Tags: r, emacs, environment, ess

I am trying to optimize my [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) - R environment. So far I make use of the [r-autoyas](http://www.svenhartenstein.de/Software/R-autoyas), I set intendation and stuff following [style guides](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html), in the mini-buffer there are eldoc hints for function arguments, and I have the option to [press a key](https://gist.github.com/318365) in order to find information about variable at point (more [here](http://www.sigmafield.org/comment/10)).

Are there any other things you use in order to have a nice R environment? Maybe non-ESS people have some nice things to add (I got that info of variable at point from looking at an Eclipser). One example could be an easy way to insert "just-before-defined" variables without typing the variable name (should be something for that?).

(Please help me to change the question instead of "closing" the thread if it is not well formulated)

Comment: Could you better describe what optimization are you looking for? I - and maybe some other people - don't know ESS. Could you describe it? Finally could you please list the commands you have already done to optimize it - not in a descriptive fashion?

Comment: I updated the post with links to the examples I mentioned. With a nice R environment I just mean to make it as comfortable and quick as possible to use R. People unfamiliar with ESS could maybe mention their favorite extension/function/plugin of their R environment that helps them optimize their workflow.

Comment: Have you tried R-Studio? I think it's one of the best IDEs for R.

Comment: Maybe mention instead what you like so much about it? That could bring something to the table.

Comment: I think ESS 100 page manual is the one you should be looking at, check out all features provided and turn on your desired ones. if you have trouble with any specific feature getting to work, ask here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not using autoyas as I find [auto-complete integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890516/453735) a better approach.

Insertion of previously defined symbols is a general emacs functionality called 'dabbrev-expand' and is bound to <kbd>M-/</kbd>. I have this in my .emacs to make it complete on full symbols:

```
(setq dabbrev-abbrev-char-regexp "\\sw\\|\\s_\\|s.")
(setq dabbrev-case-fold-search t)
```

Another thing which I use extensively is [imenu-based-jump-to-symbol-definition](http://code.google.com/p/imenu-anywhere/source/browse/trunk/imenu-anywhere.el). It offers similar functionality to emacs tags, but just for open buffers in the same mode as the current buffer. It also uses IDO for queries:

[image: imenu-anywhere screenshot]

Put `imenu-anywhere.el` into your emacs load path and add this:

```
(require 'imenu-anywhere)
(global-set-key [?\M-o] 'imenu-anywhere)
```

Now, if I do  <kbd>M-o</kbd> foo <kbd>RET</kbd> emacs jumps to the function/class/method/generic definition of 'foo' as long as 'foo' is defined in one of the open buffers. This of course works whenever a mode defines imenu-tags. ESS defines those, so you should not need to add more.

There is also somewhere a collection of R-yas templates. I didn't get around to starting using them but my guess is that it's a pretty efficient template insertion mechanism.

[edit] Activate tracebug:

```
(setq ess-use-tracebug t)
```

Comment: Could you expand on "previously defined symbols, M-/"? I can't seem to get this to work ("no dynamic expansion for X")

Comment: Could you also explain how to add an imenu tag? reading the imenu-anywhere.el doesn't help.

Comment: that auto-complete really seems useful here!

Comment: @Dualinity I have expanded my answer. If you have a word or symbol like "mySymbol" in your buffer and you type "my M-/ " then it is expanded to mySymbol.

Comment: I plan to improve imenu-anywhere and add it to MELPA in a week or so. Will give an update here once it has been done.