# source code for autocompletion in R run in terminal

Tags: r, autocomplete

I would like to study the autocomplete code of R, when R is run in a terminal. For example, if you run R from the terminal and type `lm(` and then tab, R will give you the arguments of `lm`.

Dirk's answer here suggests that autocompletion of R is supported by the codetools package which is in base R:

[Is it possible to get code completion for R in Emacs ESS similar to what is available in Rstudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865344/is-it-possible-to-get-code-completion-for-r-in-emacs-ess-similar-to-what-is-avai)

However, I can't find where in that package it adds support for autocomplete. I grepped for 'completion' and came up empty.

Comment: I *think* Dirk had the **rcompgen** package in mind not **codetools**. **rcompgen** is now subsumed within R as part of the **utils** package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The completion code is actually in the base instalation in the **utils** package. You can view everything associated with it (for the devel version) on R's SVN server:

http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/utils/R/completion.R

This code should be read in conjunction with `?completion`.

Comment: Or in prettier format from github: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/utils/R/completion.R

Comment: @Spacedman That is nicer indeed. I wish R-core would move to github but everyone has different preferences I guess.