# emacs: expand autocomplete for R function to include namespace

Tags: r, emacs, namespaces, ess

Am using EMACS/ESS as editor for `R`.

I find it helpful to refer to a function defined outside of `base` with it's relevant namespace; as well as being good practice in general, it seems to be necessary when running `R CMD check` on a package.
I really like autocomplete in EMACS and am wondering if there's a way to extend the functionality to include namespace when autocomplete-ing the name of a function.

For example (in `R`):

```
library(stats)
```

Then in `ESS` when I start typing `dn` the autocomplete `dnorm` appears (greyed out) and I can complete it by pressing `TAB`.

What would be better is to complete as `stats::dnorm` or even `stats:::dnorm` so that I don't need to manually check whether the function I'm using is in base. (For a relatively new user, memorizing the names of *all* functions in `base` may be a lot to ask).

Details:

EMACS: 2012-06-10 on MARVINGNU Emacs 24.1.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)

ESS version 12.04-4

Icicles (default install c. Oct 2012). Not sure how to find version info. for this.

If this doesn't already exist, any pointers would be welcome. Note this is [closely related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682459/emacs-autocomplete-mode-extension-for-ess-and-r) but if the answer is already there then I'm not quite getting it...